# c# 2D array - merging Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, linq

I have a 2 Dimensional string array(5*2) like this:

```
string[,] data= new string[5, 2] {{"F1","LINK1"},
{"F1","LINK2"},
{"F2","LINK3"},
{"F3","LINK4"},
{"F3","LINK5"}};
```

i want to group and merge the values into new array.

Output :

```
{"F1","LINK1,LINK2"},
{"F2","LINK3"},
{"F3","LINK4,LINK5"}
```

The output array  3*2.

Comment: Could you please represent your arrays in C# notation? "2D" means different things to different people

Comment: Agreed these are not 2d arrays, they are just lumps of text. Please read [ask] to make your experience here smoother

Comment: Do you have `string[,]` or `string[][]` arrays? Or even `List<List<string>>`?

Comment: @Rafalon I have string[,] only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```cs
string[,] data= new string[5, 2] {{"F1","LINK1"},
    {"F1","LINK2"},
    {"F2","LINK3"},
    {"F3","LINK4"},
    {"F3","LINK5"}};

var items = Enumerable.Range(0, data.GetLength(0))
    .Select(n => new {Key = data[n, 0], Link = data[n, 1]});

var query =
    from i in items
    group i by i.Key
    into g
    select new []
    {
        g.Key,
        string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Link))
    };

var result = query.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you This works i tried another way also.